# Use of business logic layer in .net

Tags: .net

I am new to 3-tier architecture.I am going through the google and found some samples.generally the database connection and methods are implemented for crud operations in Data access layer only.And the input validations like required field validation are at Presentation layer only.then why we need Business logic layer.can tell me the one situation where Business logic layer is most useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an e-commerce site - for certain combinations of products, you give a discount.

The logic for the discount doesn't belong in the UI layer - all data has been validated already (the products and amounts in the basket).

It doesn't belong in the data access layer either.

This kind of logic is determined by the business - it belongs in the Business Logic Layer, between the UI and the Data Access.